# Connect two raspberry pi together using BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, raspberry-pi4

I want to send strings between two Raspberry Pi 4s using BLE and the BluePy library. I am not sure how I can do that and also cannot obtain the Service and Characteristic IDs.

I can connect a single raspberry PI to my smart watch, but I would like to connect them with each other. Right now I would like to test out the simple case of sending a string. However, I am not sure how to get the Characteristic ID and Service ID for the raspberry PI. I am trying to use the library BluePy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65935999/ble-communication-between-two-raspberry-pi-4?rq=2.

Comment: Your smart watch will be in the BLE Peripheral role and your RPi with be the BLE Central role. To use two RPi's you will need to use one of them in the Peripheral role. BluePy library does not support creating a Peripheral. You might find the following article helpful to get you started: https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/

Comment: @ukBaz I tried this code and now have a working gatt server. However, then I found the BlueZ documentation on github, they also have a gatt server and gatt client, but the example codes they have given do not work. I am trouble setting up the client now :/

https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/test/example-gatt-server

Comment: Sounds like you need to start a new question with specific information on what's not working on your GATT client and what debug information you have.